# Chrome removes the last part of my URL in local Django web app develoment (using allauth)

Tags: python, django, google-chrome, django-allauth

Chrome removes the last part of my URL in local Django web app develoment (using django-allauth).

It replaces `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/` with `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`
So I can't access my login page frome Chrome, but it works fine with Firefox.

my **urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
)
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok That was a stupid question: I was already connected in chrome (I forgot that I was connected through the admin) and my app redirects users to my home page when they try to log in when they are already connected.

So I just had to go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/logout/` to log out before logging in.